# matplotlib y-adjustment of texts using adjustText

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

That is a plot i generated using pyplot and (attempted to) adjust the text using the adjustText library which i also found here.

as you can see, it gets pretty crowded in the parts where `0 < x < 0.1`. i was thinking that there's still ample space in `0.8 < y < 1.0` such that they could all fit and label the points pretty well.

my attempt was:

```
plt.plot(df.fpr,df.tpr,marker='.',ls='-') 
texts = [plt.text(df.fpr[i],df.tpr[i], str(df.thr1[i])) for i in df.index] 
adjust_text(texts,
            expand_text=(2,2),
            expand_points=(2,2),
            expand_objects=(2,2),
            force_objects = (2,20),
            force_points = (0.1,0.25),
            lim=150000,
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-',color='red'),
            autoalign='y',
            only_move={'points':'y','text':'y'}
            )
```

where my `df` is a pandas dataframe which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WzXV-svcfS9xXfLCsSdw-MnrqE64XJIC/view?usp=sharing)

from what i understood in the docs, i tried varying the bounding boxes and the y-force by making them larger, thinking that it would push the labels further up, but it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of adjustText, sorry I just noticed this question. you are having this problem because you have a lot of overlapping texts with exactly the same y-coordinate. It's easy to solve by adding a tiny random shift along the y to the labels (and you do need to increase the force for texts, otherwise along one dimension it works very slowly), like so:

```
np.random.seed(0)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df.fpr,df.tpr,marker='.',ls='-') 
texts = [plt.text(df.fpr[i], df.tpr[i]+np.random.random()/100, str(df.thr1[i])) for i in df.index]
plt.margins(y=0.125)
adjust_text(texts,
            force_text=(2, 2),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-',color='red'),
            autoalign='y',
            only_move={'points':'y','text':'y'},
            )
```

Also notice that I increased the margins along the y axis, it helps a lot with the corners. The result is not quite perfect, limiting the algorithm to just one axis make life more difficult... But it's OK-ish already.

[image]

Have to mention, size of the figure is very important, I don't know what yours was.